# Speed up excel formatting vba code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following vba code to change a text string date into an actual date in excel so I can use it for logical comparisons and the like.

The problem is I need this to work for around 4000 rows and update it weekly, and this code is very slow.

```
Sub Datechange()

Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
    Next c

End Sub
```

Are there any alternative ways I could do the same thing quicker? I am assuming part of the reason it is so slow is because there are overheads involved with selecting single cells and processing the code over and over but I am not sure how to do it any other way?

Also some of the rows at the bottom contain the words "None Specified" and when the code reaches these cells it breaks with

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Is there a way to stop this happening so the following code can complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First steps would be:

- Turn screen updating off
- Turn calculation off
- Read and write the range at once

It could look like the code below - it is a good idea to include an error handler to avoid leaving your spreadsheet with screen updates off or with the calculation mode changed:

```
Sub Datechange()

    On Error GoTo error_handler

    Dim initialMode As Long

    initialMode = Application.Calculation 'save calculation mode
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'turn calculation to manual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn off screen updating

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'copy range to an array
    data = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        'modify the array if the value looks like a date, else skip it
        If IsDate(data(i, 1)) Then data(i, 1) = CDate(data(i, 1))
    Next i

    'copy array back to range
    Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) = data

exit_door:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn screen updating on
    Application.Calculation = initialMode 'restore original calculation mode

    Exit Sub

error_handler:
    'if there is an error, let the user know
    MsgBox "Error encountered on line " & i + 1 & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume exit_door 'don't forget the exit door to restore the calculation mode
End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to write the same! ;-)

Only change I'd suggest: given the Type mismatch error outlined in the question, I'd rather handle the type mismatch in case a cell does not contain a date - but then continue the loop. I.e. in this case one could consider using `On Error Resume Next` (though I'd generally discourage the use of that statement)

Comment: @PeterAlbert Good point - I have added a test on the type which should avoid such a situation.

Comment: Great! Just a code-style-question/comment: Instead of using the `Goto exit_door`, would it be better to move the error_handler at the bottom and use `Resume exit_door` here - and `Exit Sub` before the error_handler?

Comment: @PeterAlbert Good point again - my vba is a bit rusty it seems ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot! at which point would i turn screen updating off and calculation off? or is that already part of the code you have posted above?

Comment: It is this part:
    initialMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
But you should change  Application.ScreenUpdating  to false at that position.

Comment: @user25704 I have added comments

Comment: Hi again, should it not be - Application.ScreenUpdating = False for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to get the values in to an array in one single "pull", operate on the array and write it back.
That would circumvent the expensive range operation.

```
dim c as range
set c = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

dim ArrValue() as Variant

set ArrValue = c.value
```

next step: iterate over that array and then write back:

```
c.value = Arrvalue
```

I have no time to test the code, so please correct it for yourself, I am sorry.