# Slow reading from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am reading an Excel file through VB 6 as following

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ExlUsedRowCount As Long

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True)
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ExlUsedRowCount = objWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For RowIndex = 1 To ExlUsedRowCount
    someVariable = Trim$(objWorksheet.Cells(RowIndex, 9))
Next

objWorkbook.Close False
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objWorksheet = Nothing
```

I have Excel 2013 and this code reads 270 lines () per second on my machine while on client side (Excel 2010) it reads only 33/sec. I have seen processes list and there is no process other than EXCEL.EXE which consumes > 80% CPU. This is the case with 4 PCs at client side.

I tried to save this file in CSV but there are date columns formatted as DD/MM and when saved as CSV, the YEAR is omitted at all. Any clue?

Please advice what might be wrong

Comment: Don't loop over the cells. Read the whole range into an array, work on the array, then put the data back into the sheet. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14336112/829571

Comment: @chrisneilsen That one is about "formatting macro" and the subject is little misleading w.r.t this question, isn't it?

Comment: Can you post the OS/CPU/RAM of the machines in question?

Comment: `UsedRange.Rows.Count` isn't always an accurate reflection of the number of used rows. `objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row` should be more accurate

Comment: @barrowc won't it make you select or loop through all rows unnecessarily? And what if it is an xlsx file!

Comment: @assylias The example worked. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lngLoop      As Long
    Dim varArrTemp      as Variant
    Dim rngData         as range

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True)
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Set rngData   = objWorksheet.UsedRange.columns(9)
    varArrtemp =rngData
    For lngLoop = Lbound(varArrTemp) To Ubound(varArrtemp)
        varArrtemp (lngLoop,9)= Trim$( varArrtemp (lngLoop,9))
    Next
    rngData   = varArrTemp

    objWorkbook.Close False
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objWorksheet = Nothing
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @assylias, i was also wondering.